# How to retrieve data from Json file into Winform with Json.Net

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I am still fairly unfamiliar with Json, but I am trying to import data from a Json file into form fields of a Winform. For this I want to use Json.NET. I found the following example at https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1201466/Working-with-JSON-in-Csharp-VB.

I have processed the code in my own form, but I cannot get the Json data into a form field.

My Json file has the following format:

```
{
"DataSource": {
    "Id": "b94809c324ee4ab5b7dfa81e00b1e535",
    "Name": "DataSourceName",
    "Headers": [{
        "Name": "ID",
        "DisplayAt": "None"
    }, {
        "Name": "Datum storing",
        "DisplayAt": "Title"
    }, {
        "Name": "Tijdstip melding",
        "DisplayAt": "None"
    }, {
        "Name": "Projectnummer",
        "DisplayAt": "None"
    }, {
        "Name": "Projectnaam",
        "DisplayAt": "None"
    }, {
        "Name": "Servicemonteur",
        "DisplayAt": "None"
    }, {
        "Name": "Start reistijd",
        "DisplayAt": "None"
    }, {
        "Name": "starttijd werkzaamheden",
        "DisplayAt": "None"
    }, {
        "Name": "eindtijd werkzaamheden",
        "DisplayAt": "None"
    }, {
        "Name": "eind reistijd",
        "DisplayAt": "None"
    }, {
        "Name": "omschrijving storing",
        "DisplayAt": "None"
    }, {
        "Name": "oorzaak storing",
        "DisplayAt": "None"
    }, {
        "Name": "omschrijving werkzaamheden",
        "DisplayAt": "None"
    }, {
        "Name": "aanbevelingen",
        "DisplayAt": "None"
    }, {
        "Name": "verbruikte materialen",
        "DisplayAt": "None"
    }, {
        "Name": "zoekstring",
        "DisplayAt": "None"
    }, {
        "Name": "categorie_ID",
        "DisplayAt": "None"
    }, {
        "Name": "melding_van",
        "DisplayAt": "None"
    }],
    "Rows": [
        ["valueId", "2018-02-26", "13:41:00", "104", "ProjectName1", "Engineer1,  Engineer2", "11:00:00", "11:30:00", "12:45:00", "13:15:00", "Omschrijving", "Onbekend", "Omschrijving 2.", "Omschrijving 3.", null, "Omschrijving 4", "1", null],
        ["valueId", "2018-03-24", "13:41:00", "104", "ProjectName2", "Engineer1,  Engineer2", "11:00:00", "11:30:00", "12:45:00", "13:15:00", "Omschrijving", "Onbekend", "Omschrijving 2.", "Omschrijving 3.", null, "Omschrijving 4", "1", null], 
        ["valueId", "2018-03-12", "18:06:00", "173", "ProjectName3", "Engineer1,  Engineer2", "11:00:00", "11:30:00", "12:45:00", "13:15:00", "Omschrijving", "Onbekend", "Omschrijving 2.", "Omschrijving 3.", null, "Omschrijving 4", "1", null]
    ],
    "TotalRows": 3,
    "LastUpdated": "2020-06-19T13:15:17.7400000Z",
    "CompanyId": 12345
  }
}
```

From this file I want to get the data from the Headers and the Rows. I started with retrieving the Headers from the file. So I made the following Class via jsonutils.com:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Namespace Models
    Public Class Header

        <JsonProperty("Name")>
        Public Property Name As String

        <JsonProperty("DisplayAt")>
        Public Property DisplayAt As String
    End Class

    Public Class DataSource

        <JsonProperty("Id")>
        Public Property Id As String

        <JsonProperty("Name")>
        Public Property Name As String

        <JsonProperty("Headers")>
        Public Property Headers As Header()

        <JsonProperty("Rows")>
        Public Property Rows As String()()

        <JsonProperty("TotalRows")>
        Public Property TotalRows As Integer

        <JsonProperty("LastUpdated")>
        Public Property LastUpdated As DateTime

        <JsonProperty("CompanyId")>
        Public Property CompanyId As Integer
    End Class

    Public Class Category

        <JsonProperty("DataSource")>
        Public Property DataSource As DataSource
    End Class

End Namespace
```

With the following code I want to get the values of the DataSource Class:

```
    Private Sub GetData()

    ' Retrieve JSON data from file
    Dim rawJson = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(filePath, fileName))

    ' Convert to C# Class typed object
    Result = JsonHelper.ToClass(Of DataSource)(rawJson)

    UpdateUI()

End Sub
```

At this point the Json File is loaded into rawJson and is going to be deserialized via the following function:

```
    Public Function ToClass(Of T)(data As String, Optional jsonSettings As JsonSerializerSettings = Nothing) As T

    Dim response = Nothing

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(data) Then
        response = If(jsonSettings Is Nothing,
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of T)(data),
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of T)(data, jsonSettings))
    End If

    Return response

End Function
```

Only the result (response) of the function stays empty, but I can't figure out why. What I want is to retrieve the data from the Headers and the Rows and fill them in my form.

Comment: You want `Dim dataSource = JsonHelper.ToClass(Of Category)(rawJson).DataSource`

Comment: @Fabio. Thnx. And how do I get the items from the rows? They are in a kind of array I think?

Comment: Found out how to get the rows. `dataSource.Rows(0)(4).ToString`